# How do I remove a character from a string in a Unix shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have several files that are named like this: file - name.txt

How do I remove the " - " using a bash script in UNIX from all the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to remove the part of the string you want to be rid of. Make sure to use double-quotes to prevent `mv` from misinterpreting input.

```bash
for i in ./*' - '*; do
    mv "$i" "${i// - }"
done
```

Comment: OK thanks! That worked! Also, using that same method, how would I be able to store the part of the filename before the " - " in a separate string?

Comment: @Generalkidd `separateString="${i%% - *}"`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, try `rename ' - ' '' *`

Comment: It exists in some distros and there are at least two inconsistent implementations. It is not a POSIX tool.

Answer (score 1):

Sed it up!

```
# Iterate each file in the current directory.
for i in *; do
  # Move the file to the new filename, replacing ' - ' with '_'
  mv "$i" `echo $i | sed 's/ - /_/g'`
done
```

Comment: Doh. I am used to zsh - fixed.